# openIddict missing AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores definition

Tags: openiddict

The extensions method `AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores` is not working as expected. I get an error indicating that `OpenIddictCoreBuilder` doesn't have the `AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores` definition.

```
// Register the OpenIddict services.
services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
{
    // Register the Entity Framework stores.
    options.AddCore().AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I have these `using`s in my project:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives;
using AuthorizationServer.Models;
using AuthorizationServer.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using OpenIddict.Core;
using OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore.Models;
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax has changed in RC3:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()

    // Register the OpenIddict core services.
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    });
```

You can read the announcement here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/608.